# Ajax post in child theme returns confirmation page instead of echo

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, post

I'm trying to enable file uploads via a simple HTML form on a Wordpress page by using an AJAX POST to `upload-manager.php`.

The problem is, when the post is triggered, the returned data is not what is being echoed in `upload-manager.php`. Instead, the data being returned is a home page in an HTML string when logged to the console.

Maybe there is a confirmation URL set somewhere in WordPress that's causing this?

I've tried using `wp_dequeue_script()` in my child theme in hopes that maybe it would prevent POST event listeners from being set via some other script in the theme.

```
//DEQUEUE Specific scripts
function project_dequeue_unnecessary_scripts() {
    wp_dequeue_script('nectar-upload');
    wp_deregister_style( 'nectar-upload' );
    wp_dequeue_script('redux-opts-field-upload-js');
    wp_deregister_style( 'redux-opts-field-upload-js' );
}

add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'project_dequeue_unnecessary_scripts' );
```

```
//DEQUEUE all scripts
function pm_remove_all_scripts() {
    global $wp_scripts;
    $wp_scripts->queue = array();
}
add_action('wp_print_scripts', 'pm_remove_all_scripts', 100);
```

Neither works.

It's also worth noting the in the dev tools network panel > XHR, I get the following:

[image]

Then after ~2 seconds it changes to:

[image]

Does this mean my jQuery AJAX POST is being redirected or something?

Please help!

Comment: Can you share your AJAX call (JavaScript) please?

Comment: What's that `wd_upload_manager.php` file, that is not a WordPress Core file.